# get full path of selected(browsed) file jsp web

Tags: mysql, database, file, jsp, upload

How can I get full path of selected file.
for example I selected logo.png
it should get `c:\user\admin\desktop\logo.png`

```
String im = request.getParameter("image");
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(im));
pstmt=con.prepareStatement("Insert into items(image) values(?)");
pstmt.setBlob(1, inputStream);
```

This code insert to datbase it show this following error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: logo.png (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

(tried everything no luck)

Comment: If you are trying to do file upload using ```<input type="file" name="file"/>```?

Comment: yes i tried using tht the problem is when i select the browse the file it just shows the file name not the full path

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do file upload to a database using JSP and Servlet the way you are doing is wrong.

You cannot get the file path from a client machine for security reasons. Even if you get the file path from client machine that file won't be available in the server, since the code runs in the server you will allways get `java.io.FileNotFoundException`.

Check [Upload files to database (Servlet + JSP + MySQL)](http://www.codejava.net/coding/upload-files-to-database-servlet-jsp-mysql) example for how to upload a file to MySQL database using JSP and Servlet.